# Getting similar rows from  Database Table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Hello friends I am having following table structure of 
quote Table

[image]

I want to access all similar quotes (which have same author_id and category_id) for a particular _id(quoteId)

Similar quotes means all columns of all those rows of this table of same category_id and same author_id.    Two quotes can be considered as similar if their authors are same and category are same.

Comment: What do you mean by similar quotes? what kind of result set are you expecting ?

Comment: lookup "sql server fulltext indexing"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same author ID and category ID?

```
SELECT `related_quote`.*
FROM `quote` AS `main_quote`
LEFT JOIN `quote` AS `related_quote` USING(`author_id`, `category_id`)
WHERE `main_quote`.`_id` = QUOTE_ID
```

This will get you the original quote (ie. QUOTE_ID), and all related to it.

```
mysql> SELECT `related_quote`.*
    -> FROM `quote` AS `main_quote`
    -> LEFT JOIN `quote` AS `related_quote` USING(`author_id`, `category_id`)
    -> WHERE `main_quote`.`_id` = 1;
+------+----------------+-----------+-------------+
| _id  | content        | author_id | category_id |
+------+----------------+-----------+-------------+
|    1 | test           |         1 |           1 |
|    2 | test related   |         1 |           1 |
|    3 | test related 2 |         1 |           1 |
+------+----------------+-----------+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

You can remove the QUOTE_ID from the resultset by simply adding

```
AND `related_quote`.`_id` != QUOTE_ID
```

to the end of the query.

Comment: No prob, added a quick clause you can tag on the end to exclude the current query from the resultset.

Comment: ya thanks to let me know about this so that from result i can remove the one

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
    q1.* 
from 
    quotes q1
inner join 
   (select
      author_id,
      category_id
    from 
        quotes
    where 
        _id = 1) q2
ON 
    q1.author_id = q2.author_id
AND 
    q1.category_id = q2.category_id
```

Comment: in this query if quote table's alias is q1 then what is q2 ?

Comment: The join (ie. original quote).